# Why the ransack not searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I install ransack gem on my rails application(4.1.8).
However, when I doing the search, it would simply return all the objects.
Here is what it happen in the rails console:

```
AdminUser.ransack({email: "keyword"}).result.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"admin_users\".* FROM \"admin_users\""
```

The sql clause would only return all the AdminUser from database.
Could anyone help me with ransack?

Comment: Try reading their [wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching)

Comment: You would probably want to add email_eq or email_cont in your query.

Comment: @ j-dexx, thanks a lot, I missed the **predicates** inside my hash!

Comment: @Amit Badheka Pykih Staff yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To complete @j-dexx comment, the solution pass to include any of the [available predicates](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) after the column name.

For example, if you want to do an exact match search, you would use the **[eq](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#eq-equals)** predicate:

```
AdminUser.ransack(email_eq: 'keyword').result.to_sql
=> "SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` 
    WHERE `admin_users`.`email` = 'keyword'"
```